# How would I translate screen coordinates to Isometric coordinates?

Tags: mathematics, isometric

I have a function `isoToScreen(x, y)` that converts Isometric coordinates to Screen coordinates.

```
var tileW = 16;
var tileH = 16;

var isoToScreen = function(x, y) {
    var posX = (x - y) * tileW;
    var posY = (x + y) * tileH / 2;

    return [posX, posY];
};
```

But how would I make a function that converts screen coordinates back to Isometric coordinates?

```
var pos = screenToIso(16, 8); 
pos[0] = 1; // Iso X
pos[1] = 0; // Iso Y
```

Comment: I don't understand how this function works... I mean, if you input 0,0, you get 0,0 out, and that's clearly not screen coordinates for any isometric view I understand.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var screenToIso = function(screenX, screenY)
{
  var isoX = screenY / tileH + screenX / (2*tileW)
  var isoY = screenY / tileH - screenX / (2*tileW)

  return [isoX, isoY];
}
```

To get this function you need to rewrite the original math

```
screenX = (isoX - isoY) * tileW
screenY = (isoX + isoY) * tileH / 2
```

Starting with the first line you get the following:

```
screenX = (isoX - isoY) * tileW
screenX / tileW = isoX - isoY
screenX / tileW + isoY = isoX
```

The second line:

```
screenY = (isoX + isoY) * tileH / 2
2*screenY = (isoX + isoY) * tileH
2*screenY / tileH = isoX + isoY
2*screenY / tileH - isoX = isoY
```

Now the two lines look as follows:

```
A) isoX = screenX / tileW + isoY
B) isoY = 2*screenY / tileH - isoX
```

Then substitute isoY in the line A, with the formula derived from line B:

```
isoX = screenX / tileW + 2*screenY/tileH - isoX
isoX+isoX = screenX / tileW + 2*screenY/tileH
2*isoX = screenX / tileW + 2*screenY/tileH
isoX = screenX / (2*tileW) + screenY/tileH
isoX = screenY/tileH + screenX / (2*tileW)
```

And finally, substitute isoX in line B, with the formula derived from line A:

```
isoY = 2*screenY / tileH - screenX / tileW - isoY
2*isoY = 2*screenY / tileH - screenX / tileW
isoY = screenY / tileH - screenX / (2*tileW)
```

Solving linear equations comes very much in handy for a lot of programming, especially graphics or game related programming. Pick up a book on [Algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_algebra) or read some online tutorials, you will thank yourself later.

Comment: I know I am not good in math, and this page clearly proof it! Great!

Answer (score 3):

Just reverse the order of operations:

```
var tileW = 16;
var tileH = 16;

function screenToIso(x, y)
{
    var posX = ((y * 2 / tileH) + (x / tileW))/2;
    var posY = (y * 2 / tileH) - posX;

    return [posX, posY];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply and code! I am try this code, but... isoToScreen(10, 0); -> 160, 80. screenToIso(160, 80) -> 90, -150; :(

Comment: Whoops, you're right.  Fixed