# Trying to subdivide an ISO tile

Tags: 2d, graphics-programming

I have code that calculates where the user clicked inside an iso tile in an isometric map. The tile has a width of 1 unit and a height of 0.5 units. My code calculates where they touched inside the tile in these same units. The goal is to then decide where that click falls if you sub-divided the iso tile into a 4x4 grid. The picture below shows how all this is supposed to look.

[image]

I have found ascreen co-ordinates to iso formula and it makes sense but for whatever reason, when I try to use it with my data above I get wrong outputs. When clicking from the top corner to the right corner, only the X iso output should change but both the X and the Y change.

I feel like this should be pretty simple but after hours of banging my head against this I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Source for screen to iso formula:
[How would I translate screen coordinates to Isometric coordinates?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/30566/how-would-i-translate-screen-coordinates-to-isometric-coordinates)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
float touchedX;
float touchedY;
//below 0.125 represents the tile height because the whole thing
// is 0.5 and its 4 tiles high so 0.125, 0.5 is 2*width which 
//is (1 / 4.0) * 2
float gridPointLedftDown = (touchedY / 0.125f) + (touchedX / 0.5f);
float gridPointRightDown = (touchedY / 0.125f) - (touchedX / 0.5f);
```

Comment: hint: when you have both iso-coordinates and screen-coordinates in the same project, calling both `x` and `y` can become quite confusing. In one project where I used iso-coordinates I used the convention to call the axis' of the iso-coordinate system `l` and `r` (for left-down and right-down) instead. That really helped me a lot to keep my code understandable.

Comment: Updated the code to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the formula I had from that other site was just wrong. IsoY should be calculated as y / tileHeight - x/ tileWidth. The *2 on tileWidth when removed made the values come out correctly.